# Compare two JSON objects and just return another JSON object with only the changes

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to JavaScript and trying to find the difference between two JSON Objects. The structure of the JSON object and its data is shown below. I got a code online which works for a normal JSON object but as this also has an array of data, I think it doesnt work for that. I tried different things but to no result. If you have pointers for this, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**JSON Object 1(obj1) :**  `{id: 1, details: Array[2], profession: "Business"}`

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "details": [{
      "name": "Peter",
      "address": "Arizona",
      "phone": 9900998899
    },
    {
      "name": "Jam",
      "address": "Kentucky",
      "phone": 56034033343
    }
  ],
  "profession": "Business"
}
```

**JSON Object 2(obj2) :** `{id: 2, details: Array[2], profession: "Business"}`

```
{
  "id": "2",
  "details": [{
      "name": "Peter",
      "address": "Arizona",
      "phone": 9900998899
    },
    {
      "name": "David",
      "address": "Boston",
      "phone": 434323434
    }
  ],
  "profession": "Business"
}
```

**Solution:**

```
compare(obj1, obj2) {

  var result = {};

  for (key in obj1) {
    if (obj2[key] != obj1[key]) {
      result[key] = obj2[key];
    }
    if (typeof obj2[key] === '[object Array]' && typeof obj1[key] === '[object Array]') {
      result[key] = compare(obj1[key], obj2[key]);
    }
    if (typeof obj2[key] === 'object' && typeof obj1[key] === 'object') {
      result[key] = compare(obj1[key], obj2[key]);
    }
  }
  console.log(result);
}
```

**Result:**

```
Object {0: undefined, 1: undefined}
Object {id: "2", pingedAddresses: undefined, type: "Business"}
```

**Expected:**

```
{
  "id": "2",
  "details": [{
    "name": "David",
    "address": "Boston",
    "phone": 434323434
  }]
}
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: You will never get `[object Array]` as type. To get that, you will have to do `Object.prototype.toString.apply(obj)`. Also if you wish to check array, use `Array.isArray`

Comment: consider using underscore (or any other library you prefer) if you can, no need to invent the wheel unless your task is to invent it

Comment: can you give an example of what that new object would look like

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal editted the question and added the expected output

Comment: What if Peter and David had swapped positions, and why is Jam not considered a difference?

Comment: look into using this library https://github.com/srcagency/object-diff

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try following as a simple comparison:

**Note:** This answer assumes the structure to be exactly same. You can take this as reference and make it more generic for cases where structures are different.

**Points to consider:**

- Number of items are different. `o1.details` have 2 entries and `o2.details` have say 5 entries.
- Object structure is different. Properties in both object are different.

```js
function getDifference(o1, o2) {
  var diff = {};
  var tmp = null;
  if (JSON.stringify(o1) === JSON.stringify(o2)) return;

  for (var k in o1) {
    if (Array.isArray(o1[k]) && Array.isArray(o2[k])) {
      tmp = o1[k].reduce(function(p, c, i) {
        var _t = getDifference(c, o2[k][i]);
        if (_t)
          p.push(_t);
        return p;
      }, []);
      if (Object.keys(tmp).length > 0)
        diff[k] = tmp;
    } else if (typeof(o1[k]) === "object" && typeof(o2[k]) === "object") {
      tmp = getDifference(o1[k], o2[k]);
      if (tmp && Object.keys(tmp) > 0)
        diff[k] = tmp;
    } else if (o1[k] !== o2[k]) {
      diff[k] = o2[k]
    }
  }
  return diff;
}

var o1={id:"1",details:[{name:"Peter",address:"Arizona",phone:9900998899},{name:"Jam",address:"Kentucky",phone:56034033343}],profession:"Business"},
o2={id:"2",details:[{name:"Peter",address:"Arizona",phone:9900998899},{name:"David",address:"Boston",phone:434323434}],profession:"Business"};

var d = getDifference(o1, o2)
console.log(d)
```

I had written an answer [to detect changes in objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42464838/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-determine-if-a-collection-of-objects-has-chang/42466050#42466050). You can even take reference from this as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a for loop over the first object and check whether the second one has it or not. Then save it to a new third object:

```
 var obj3={};
 for (var key in obj1)
 {
    !obj2.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj3[key]=obj[key];

 }
```

Comment: Don't forget that obj2 must have more members than obj1.

Answer (score -1):

Affiliation: I am the author of this lib.

https://eggachecat.github.io/jycm-json-diff-viewer/

You can easily get your desried result by using the diff result. (see **Diff Result** in the screenshot!)

[image]

Step by step:

1. install deps

```bash
yarn add jycm
```

2. use the lib

```js
const {
    YouchamaJsonDiffer,
    ListItemFieldMatchOperator,
    make_ignore_order_func
} = require('jycm');

const left = {
  "id": "1",
  "details": [
    {
      "name": "Peter",
      "address": "Arizona",
      "phone": 9900998899
    },
    {
      "name": "Jam",
      "address": "Kentucky",
      "phone": 56034033343
    }
  ],
  "profession": "Business"
};

const right = {
  "id": "2",
  "details": [
    {
      "name": "Peter",
      "address": "Arizona",
      "phone": 9900998899
    },
    {
      "name": "David",
      "address": "Boston",
      "phone": 434323434
    }
  ],
  "profession": "Business"
};
const ycm = new YouchamaJsonDiffer(left, right, {operators: [], ignore_orders: []});

const diffResult = ycm.get_diff();
console.log(diffResult);
```

You can get

```json
{
  "list:add": [
    {
      "left": "__NON_EXIST__",
      "right": {
        "name": "David",
        "address": "Boston",
        "phone": 434323434
      },
      "left_path": "",
      "right_path": "details->[1]"
    }
  ],
  "list:remove": [
    {
      "left": {
        "name": "Jam",
        "address": "Kentucky",
        "phone": 56034033343
      },
      "right": "__NON_EXIST__",
      "left_path": "details->[1]",
      "right_path": ""
    }
  ],
  "value_changes": [
    {
      "left": "1",
      "right": "2",
      "left_path": "id",
      "right_path": "id",
      "old": "1",
      "new": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

3. make use of the result.

It seems like you only care about the new values from operation addition and value_change, thus simply extract these changes:

```js
console.log({
  ...diffResult["value_changes"].reduce(
    (prev, record) => ({ ...prev, [record.right_path]: record.right }),
    {}
  ),
  details: diffResult["list:add"].map((v) => v.right),
});
```

Or here's a codesniffet:

```js
const {
  YouchamaJsonDiffer,
  ListItemFieldMatchOperator,
  make_ignore_order_func,
} = jycm;

const left = {
  id: "1",
  details: [
    {
      name: "Peter",
      address: "Arizona",
      phone: 9900998899,
    },
    {
      name: "Jam",
      address: "Kentucky",
      phone: 56034033343,
    },
  ],
  profession: "Business",
};

const right = {
  id: "2",
  details: [
    {
      name: "Peter",
      address: "Arizona",
      phone: 9900998899,
    },
    {
      name: "David",
      address: "Boston",
      phone: 434323434,
    },
  ],
  profession: "Business",
};
const ycm = new YouchamaJsonDiffer(left, right, {
  operators: [],
  ignore_orders: [],
});

const diffResult = ycm.get_diff();
console.log({
  ...diffResult["value_changes"].reduce(
    (prev, record) => ({ ...prev, [record.right_path]: record.right }),
    {}
  ),
  details: diffResult["list:add"].map((v) => v.right),
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jycm@0.2.0/dist/index.js"></script>
```